# Rich client choice for an intranet web application with 5000+ users

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-mvc, wpf, rich-client-platform

For an intranet web application with 5000+ users we need to develop highly interactive (as few  postbacks as possible) client. So performance issue might arise. What would be your choice and why?

- ASP.NET Web Forms + JQuery/Ajax

  - ASP.NET Web  Forms + Silverlight

  - ASP.NET MVC + JQuery/Ajax

  - ASP.NET MVC + Silverlight

 - WPF

 - Smartclient

You may suggest any other libraries (only for .net world). Share your toughts please.

Comment: You may have to supply a bit more information than this - "highly interactive" and "various reporting services" might not quite cut it to make a professional recommendation. I myself don't know anything about the .net world - just an observation.

Comment: What's wrong with straight-up Silverlight with a WCF backend?

Comment: Pekka, corrected as you suggested.

Comment: Robert, there is nothing wrong with Silverlight with a WCF backend. Give your reasoning please as an answer maybe.

Comment: Added one more sentence about perfonmance.

Comment: Voted down.  This makes no sense.  No RIA technology is going to make your "postbacks" less severe.  Your users need the data to make business decisions or you don't.  What are you going to do?  Offer different data because or your UI framework?  Performance might be critical?  What does that even mean?  IMHO this smells like a "business type" or pointed haired boss trying to play technologist.

Comment: what is the relation between the correct data and postbacks?? data can be retrieved via ajax calls retrieving not the whole page but only  data needed. in this way client side can be more responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asp.net + commercial reporting tool(for example: telerik) + pure asp.net ajax

reasons:

-because it's intranet application, speed in context of bandwidth and page size it is not issue, and viewstate it's not concern

-for reporting, asp.net it is very good because of using of controls which you can bind to data very fast and easily...if you put on top of that some asp.net commercial reporting tool like telerik, I think you get pretty stable and robust system

-unfortunately, asp.net and jquery don't work well together(asp.net id generation issues) so I will recommend asp.net ajax, it fits nicely in whole asp.net page lifecycle system

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Have you ruled out using SharePoint as a foundation? I played with the SharePoint 2010 beta for a few weeks and they seem to be using Silverlight a lot in there and I suspect the integration will be getting better and better.

I have a love/hate relationship with SharePoint as my profile states, but using Silverlight and/or jQuery for page customization has been a huge improvement. You get a lot of stuff for "free" from SharePoint that you'd spend a lot of time implementing in ASP.NET for an intranet such as authentication, profiles, dashboard/web part functionality, document libraries with version control, etc. I cringe every time I work with SharePoint 2007 but deep down inside I know it's better than starting from scratch.

Comment: I agree. With a large intranet application using a feature rich platform like sharepoint will likely provide support for a huge chunk of your application's core requirements right out of the box... especially the plumbing type features. It also gives you a means to purchase many additional features from your requirements from 3rd party sources. This allows you to save those expensive developers for the features you truly cannot buy that are unique to your environment.

Comment: I'm also with Josh on the love/hate relationship with sharepoint. I cannot argue that it is a great platform in some situations, but I dislike working with it myself.